# Find the delta between two xelements using "except" C#

Tags: c#, xml, comparison, xelement

My first XElement is:

```
XElement sourceFile = new XElement("source",
                from o in Version1.Element("folder").Elements("folders").ElementAt(0).Elements("folder")
                where o.Name != null && o.Name == "folder"
                select new XElement("data",
                    new XElement("name",(string) o.Attribute("name")),
                    new XElement("filesCount", (string)o.Attribute("folderCount")),
                    new XElement("filesCount", (string)o.Attribute("filesCount"))
            )); 
            //,o)
```

My second is:

```
XElement targetFile = new XElement("target",
            from o in Version2.Element("folder").Elements("folders").ElementAt(0).Elements("folder")
            where o.Name != null && o.Name == "folder"
            select new XElement("data",
                new XElement("name", (string)o.Attribute("name")),
                new XElement("filesCount", (string)o.Attribute("folderCount")),
                new XElement("filesCount", (string)o.Attribute("filesCount"))
        ));
```

I'd like to find the delta (the source always contains the target)
something like this... sadly my is not working:

```
XElement nodenotinsource = new XElement ("result",
            from y in sourceFile.Elements().Except(from o in targetFile.Elements())
           select new XElement("ttt", y.Element("name").Value));
```

Version1 and Version2 were created like this:

```
XElement Version1 = XElement.Load(@"C:\output\xmltestO.xml");
XElement Version2 = XElement.Load(@"C:\output\xmltestO.xml");
```

where the two files are the same except the change the program should find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(In the code in your question, you are loading the *same file* into `Version1` and `Version2`. I’ll assume this is a typo and you are actually loading different files.)

You can’t use `Except` to compare `XElement`s. You are creating separate instances of `XElement`. Even though they contain the same contents, they will not compare as equal.

Therefore, you need to compare the original data. For example:

```
var sourceData =
    from o in Version1.Element("folder").Elements("folders").ElementAt(0).Elements("folder")
    where o.Name != null && o.Name == "folder"
    select new {
        Name = (string) o.Attribute("name")),
        FolderCount = (string)o.Attribute("folderCount")),
        FilesCount = (string)o.Attribute("filesCount"))
    };
```

Then do the same with the target file to get `targetData`. Finally, you can compare them using `Except` and then generate your final `XElement`:

```
XElement nodenotinsource = new XElement ("result",
    from y in sourceData.Except(targetData)
    select new XElement("ttt", y.Name));
```