# Adding arrays without copying duplicate values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, union, intersection

What is the fastest way to do this:

```
var firstArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray(); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
var secondArray = Enumerable.Range(9, 3).ToArray(); //                 9,10,11,12
var thirdArray = Enumerable.Range(2, 3).ToArray();  //   2,3,4,5
//add these arrays expected output would be            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

Is there a linq way to do this. I quite have a huge list of array to iterate. another example

```
var firstArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray(); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
var secondArray = Enumerable.Range(12, 1).ToArray(); //                     12,13
//add these arrays expected output would be            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13
```

*Note: I prefer a function that would work on date ranges.*

Comment: similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325810/how-to-compare-list-of-x-to-list-of-y-in-c-by-using-generics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.Union` will give you the distinct combination of various sequences. Note: if you are working with a custom type, you will need to provide overrides for `GetHashCode/Equals` inside the class or provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your type in an overload. For BCL types such as `int` or `DateTime`, you will be fine.

Example:

```
var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Union(Enumerable.Range(5,10));
// should result in sequence of 0 through 14, no repeats
```

**Edit**

> What would be the elegant way to union all my ranges without chaining them all in one command.

If you have a sequence of sequences, be it a collection of lists, perhaps a jagged array, you can use the `SelectMany` method along with `Distinct`.

```
int[][] numberArrays = new int[3][];
numberArrays[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
numberArrays[1] = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
numberArrays[2] = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };

var allUniqueNumbers = numberArrays.SelectMany(i => i).Distinct();
```

Otherwise, you might consider creating your own extension method that could handle this.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> UnionMany<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, params IEnumerable<T>[] others)
    {
        return sequence.Union(others.SelectMany(i => i));
    }
}

//

var allUniques = numberArrays[0].UnionMany(numberArrays[1], numberArrays[2]);
```

Comment: What would be the elegant way to union all my ranges without chaining them all in one command.

Comment: last, how about a List<int32[]> ?

Comment: @geocine, `SelectMany` method still applies. `int[]` is an implementer of `IEnumerable<T>`, `List<>` is an implementer as well. Same LINQ code that works for `int[][]` works for the above collection, and would work for `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`.